# Non-submit button in oTree

Tags: form-submit, otree

I have a form made of buttons and a submit button. I want to submit only from the submit button.

I tried to use button type="button", but when I try to submit I get a "This field is required" error. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the Blank = True in models.py for the fields that do not submit?